# Create secondary index using coprocesor HBase

Tags: hadoop, indexing, hbase

I've been trying to write my own coprocessor that creates a secondary index using the prePut hook.  To start, I've been simply trying to get a prePut coprocessor to work.  So far I can have the coprocessor add to the put object passed to it.  What i've found is that I cannot get the coprocessor to write to a row separate from what the passed in put object is writing to.  Obviously to create a secondary index, I need to figure this one out.

Below is the code for my coprocessor, but it doesn't work.
Yes, all tables exists, and  'colfam1' exists too.
HBase Version: HBase 0.92.1-cdh4.1.2 from Cloudera's CDH4

Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
    @Override
        public void prePut(final ObserverContext<RegionCoprocessorEnvironment> e,final Put put, final WALEdit edit, final boolean writeToWAL) throws IOException {          
            KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(Bytes.toBytes("COPROCESSORROW"), Bytes.toBytes("colfam1"),Bytes.toBytes("COPROCESSOR: "+System.currentTimeMillis()),Bytes.toBytes("IT WORKED"));
            put.add(kv);
        }
```

I get the following error:

```
    ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 1 action: IOException: 1 time, servers with issues:
```

UPDATE:

I've modified my coprocessor to the following, but I'm still getting an error.  Now the post-Put (secondary index) is written, but there is still a timeout error.
The entire table on the region crashes too requiring me to restart the region.  Sometimes a region restart doesn't work and the entire region (all tables)
 are corrupted requiring a server rebuild.

I have no idea why...!?

```
@Override
      public void start(CoprocessorEnvironment env) throws IOException {        
        LOG.info("(start)");
        pool = new HTablePool(env.getConfiguration(), 10);
     }

    @Override
    public void postPut(final ObserverContext<RegionCoprocessorEnvironment> observerContext,final Put put,final WALEdit edit,final boolean writeToWAL) throws IOException {
        byte[] tableName  = observerContext.getEnvironment().getRegion().getRegionInfo().getTableName();

        //not necessary though if you register the coprocessor for the specific table , SOURCE_TBL
        if (!Bytes.equals(tableName, Bytes.toBytes(SOURCE_TABLE))) 
            return;         

        try {           
            LOG.info("STARTING postPut");
            HTableInterface table = pool.getTable(Bytes.toBytes(INDEX_TABLE));
            LOG.info("TURN OFF AUTOFLUSH");
            table.setAutoFlush(false);
            //create row              
            LOG.info("Creating new row");            
            byte [] rowkey = Bytes.toBytes("COPROCESSOR ROW");
            Put indexput  = new Put(rowkey); 
            indexput.add(Bytes.toBytes ( "data"),  Bytes.toBytes("CP: "+System.currentTimeMillis()),  Bytes.toBytes("IT WORKED!"));
            LOG.info("Writing to table");
            table.put(indexput);
            LOG.info("flushing commits");            
            table.flushCommits();
            LOG.info("close table");
            table.close();

        } catch ( IllegalArgumentException ex) {

            //handle excepion.
        }

      }


      @Override
      public void stop(CoprocessorEnvironment env) throws IOException {
        LOG.info("(stop)");
        pool.close();
      }
```

Here is the region server log: (note my logging comments)

```
2013-01-30 19:30:39,754 INFO my.package.MyCoprocessor: STARTING postPut
2013-01-30 19:30:39,754 INFO my.package.MyCoprocessor: TURN OFF AUTOFLUSH
2013-01-30 19:30:39,755 INFO my.package.MyCoprocessor: Creating new row
2013-01-30 19:30:39,755 INFO my.package.MyCoprocessor: Writing to table
2013-01-30 19:30:39,755 INFO my.package.MyCoprocessor: flushing commits
2013-01-30 19:31:39,813 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Failed all from region=test_table,,1359573731255.d41b77b31fafa6502a8f09db9c56b9d8., hostname=node01, port=60020
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Call to node01/<private_ip>:60020 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/<private_ip>:56390 remote=node01/<private_ip>:60020]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatchCallback(HConnectionManager.java:1557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatch(HConnectionManager.java:1409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:949)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool$PooledHTable.flushCommits(HTablePool.java:449)
    at my.package.MyCoprocessor.postPut(MyCoprocessor.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost.postPut(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:682)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.doMiniBatchPut(HRegion.java:1901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.put(HRegion.java:1742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.multi(HRegionServer.java:3102)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1345)
```

Solved: I was trying to write to the same table in my coprocoessor that the coprocessor was working on:  in short, when I wrote a cell, the CP wrote a cell causing the CP to trigger again and write another and so on and on.  I stopped it by doing a row check b4 writting the CP row to prevent this loop.

Comment: I know its bit late but can you share a working example of code. I have similar need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is snippet of code on how we use Coprocessors in Hbase to create secondary index. Can be helpful to you.

```
public class TestCoprocessor extends BaseRegionObserver{

    private HTablePool pool = null;

    private final static String  INDEX_TABLE  = "INDEX_TBL";
    private final static String  SOURCE_TABLE = "SOURCE_TBL";

    @Override
    public void start(CoprocessorEnvironment env) throws IOException {  
        pool = new HTablePool(env.getConfiguration(), 10);
    }

    @Override
    public void postPut(
        final ObserverContext<RegionCoprocessorEnvironment> observerContext,
        final Put put,
        final WALEdit edit,
        final boolean writeToWAL)
        throws IOException {

        byte[] table = observerContext.getEnvironment(
            ).getRegion().getRegionInfo().getTableName();

        // Not necessary though if you register the coprocessor
        // for the specific table, SOURCE_TBL
        if (!Bytes.equals(table, Bytes.toBytes(SOURCE_TABLE))) {
            return; 
        }

        try {
            final List<KeyValue> filteredList = put.get(
                Bytes.toBytes ( "colfam1"), Bytes.toBytes(" qaul"));
            filteredList.get( 0 ); //get the column value

            // get the values 
            HTableInterface table = pool.getTable(Bytes.toBytes(INDEX_TABLE));

            // create row key             
            byte [] rowkey = mkRowKey () //make the row key
            Put indexput = new Put(rowkey); 
            indexput.add(
                Bytes.toBytes( "colfam1"),
                Bytes.toBytes(" qaul"),
                Bytes.toBytes(" value.."));

            table.put(indexput);
            table.close();

        } catch ( IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            // handle excepion.
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void stop(CoprocessorEnvironment env) throws IOException {
        pool.close();
    }

}
```

To register the above coprocessor on the SOURCE_BL, go to the hbase shell  and follow the below steps

1. disable 'SOURCE_TBL'
2. alter 'SOURCE_TBL', METHOD =>
   'table_att','coprocessor'=>'file:///path/to/coprocessor.jar|TestCoprocessor|1001'
3. enable 'SOURCE_TBL'

Comment: I tried but it failed.  I have a preGet in the same coprocessor that works.  Here's the error: Failed all from region=test_table,,1359425096640.2e1ee8eb761a60df52f0f1937a5482d4., hostname=node01, port=60020
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Call to node01/:60020 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=node01:52214 remote=node01:60020]

Answer (score -2):

Secondary indexes have been built into HBase now. Look at this [blog entry](http://blog.rajeevsharma.in/2009/06/secondary-indexes-in-hbase.html) for the same. There is no need to use CoProcessors in HBase for the same.

Comment: I came across that website when I was looking for an answer to this.  As I mentioned, I'm using CDH4, and I did not see anything that supports secondary indexing like that blog suggests.  Do I need to add something to CDH4 to support it or am I not looking in the right place?

Comment: Secondary indexes were removed at the same time Coprocessors were introduced. Coprocessors are well-fitted for writing indexes.